# PowerShell: Cache Bytes Memory Counter

Tags: caching, memory, powershell, counter

I am trying to get the total number of cached bytes on a windows 2012 server system using PowerShell and there seems to be some contradiction in Microsoft's documentation of this metric.

According to [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> The Memory\Cache Bytes performance counter is the sum of the Memory\System Cache Resident Bytes, Memory\System Driver Resident Bytes, Memory\System Code Resident Bytes, and Memory\Pool Paged Resident Bytes counters.

However, when I query the following PowerShell cmdlets, I get varying results.

```
get-counter -counter "\Memory\Cache Bytes"
```

returns around 50 MB, whereas

```
(get-counter -counter "\Memory\System Cache Resident Bytes").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue +
(get-counter -counter "\Memory\System Driver Resident Bytes").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue + 
(get-counter -counter "\Memory\System Code Resident Bytes").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue + 
(get-counter -counter "\Memory\Pool Paged Resident Bytes").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue
```

returns around 201 MB.

I also checked these values with the cached value in the task manager, which shows a value of around 500 MB.

Anybody have any ideas as to which value is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to note that while the Microsoft documentation I linked to points to documentation on a WMI class, the performance counters I used here are property qualifiers for the corresponding WMI objects. So they return the same values.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks manager is showing standby memory + modified. It should match resmon.msc memory "cached" amount. Run this in PowerShell to get a close match.

```
((Get-Counter -Counter "\memory\*"|select -ExpandProperty countersamples|? {($_.path -ilike "*\memory\standby*")-or ($_.path -ilike "*\memory\modified page list bytes")}).cookedvalue|Measure-Object -Sum).Sum/1000MB`
```